# After installing Windows 10, I want to disable the Synaptics pointing device

Tags: windows, touchpad

After installing Windows 10, I want to disable the Synaptics pointing device when I have a mouse plugged into a USB port. I checked the box for this disable feature, but when I log back on I must disable it again. I do not want the Synaptics pointing device to work when I use the mouse.

Comment: Found [this](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-turn-off-touchpad-when-mouse-is-connected-in-windows-78-1/) for Windows 7/8 Its worth giving a try

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at this issue for a while now.  Unfortunately, this is now a windows "feature".  What I did, although not a complete solution, was to pin the mouse settings to the start menu.  So after a reboot, I clink on the icon in the start menu and go to advanced settings and turn it off (again).